# How can I deal Numpy object in Numpy object?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I wanna to make a multi-classification model from [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data).

When I deal labels with `Keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator - flow_from_dataframe`,

y_train:

```
array([array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),
       array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)],
      dtype=object)
```

it returns above result. From this result, my model recognize only one BIG array, not separated array. How can I get normal 2D-shape Numpy array?

my codes:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
gen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        rotation_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
```

xray_data['target_vector']

```
0         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
1         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
2         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
                             ...                    
112115    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
112116    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
112117    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
112118    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
112119    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Name: target_vector, Length: 112120, dtype: object
```

```
train_gen = gen.flow_from_dataframe(xray_data, x_col='full_path', y_col='target_vector', class_mode='raw')
```

```
X_train, y_train = train_gen.next()
```

-> above result..

Thank you for your kind answers!

Comment: that work fine you got one hot encoded vector for y, what the actual problem?